# Is there a better way to map multiple headers from an input file to a class model?

Tags: c#

I receive a variety of input files (CSV, Excel) from clients that all feed into the same data model.  The clients all use different headers for their data so I need to map the header options to a single field in a data model.

Example: I have a field Company in the class model and the possible headers I need to read from might be Firm, Company, CompanyName, or Business.

Right now I'm using a large repetitive switch statement to handle this based on the headers that I've seen.  This is working but it's really ugly and repetitive.

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var colKey = "";

switch (columnName.ToUpper())
{
    case "FIRM":
    case "COMPANY":
    case "COMPANYNAME":
    case "BUSINESS":
        colKey = "COMPANY";
        if (!map.ContainsKey( colKey ))
        {
            map.Add( colKey, columnName);
        }
        break;
    case "ADDRESS1":
    case "LINE1":
        colKey = "LINE1";
        if (!map.ContainsKey ( colKey ))
        {
            map.Add( colKey, columnName);
        }
        break;
}
```

Ultimately I need to read the data out of DataRows that may have a variety of headers into a data model.  The above code gives me a dictionary I can use to access the data by a known name even though the data's header may not match my data model.

Is there a better way to map/parse these possible header options into a data model field?

Comment: `if (columnName ==  "FIRM" || columnName ==  "Company" || …)`

Comment: I would have one function `string GetColumnName(string columnName)` which return COMPANY/LINE1 etc. You cannot avoid switch or if else here. And then add result to the dictionary. It will reduce some of the duplicate code.

Comment: @Fhnaseer That would certainly cut down on the duplicate code, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: You can use dictionaries to store column mappings as well, but I will just stick to if else conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is something you can't control I would put the mapping either in some config file or in the database. There you can change or add new mapping easily + you don't need to recompile your program every time when new header comes.

I had a similar problem and I solved it by storing mappings between my keys and client headers into the database:

```
MapTo       MapFrom
-------------------------------------    
COMPANY | FIRM,BUSINESS,COMPANYNAME |
-------------------------------------
LINE1   | LINE!,ADDRESS1            |
-------------------------------------
```

Now in your program you just query the database and store mappings into an `Dictionary<string, string[]>` where `key` holds `MaptTo` and `value` holds `MapFrom`.

You can also have some caching involved if you don't want to query the database every time you need the mapping.

When your dictionary is ready you can now easily find your match by using `Linq` (this is more like a pseudo code, but you will get the idea):

```
// load mappings - and cache them if possible
var mappings = _repo.GetMappings();
// find your match
var match = mappings.SingleOrDefault(
    x => x.Value.Any(
        v => v.Equals(columnName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
// take the key - you can do this also in the linq above
var colKey = match.Key;
```

Of course you will need to add here null checks and improve the code, but this is just for you to get the idea.

The benefit is that your clients will not ruin your code with their weird header column names and your code will be clean and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

since the columnMappings are predefined, we could have a static Dictionary with all possible column names as key, and the colKey as the value like:

```
  static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _columnMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  static ClassName() //static constructor
  {
     _columnMappings.Add("FIRM", "COMPANY");
     _columnMappings.Add("COMPANY", "COMPANY");
     _columnMappings.Add("COMPANYNAME", "COMPANY");
     _columnMappings.Add("BUSINESS", "COMPANY");
     _columnMappings.Add("ADDRESS1", "LINE1");
     _columnMappings.Add("LINE1", "LINE1");
  }
```

And could be used like:

```
 var columnName = "FIRM";
 var map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 var colKey = string.Empty;
 if (_columnMappings.TryGetValue(columnName, out colKey))
    map.Add(colKey, columnName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid writing the mapping itself, but you can create a dictionary using dictionary initializer that will make it a bit more pretty (plus some constants):

```
const string companyColumnName = "COMPANY";
var map = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   {"FIRM", companyColumnName },
   {"Company", companyColumnName },
   // Etc.
};
```